# epsilon delta definition of limit with $ |x-a| < \delta$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I need to prove that if I change the definition from $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ to $ |x-a| < \delta $ then the definitions are not the same, meaning it won't work for all cases.

So I took as an example $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ so I said that if we try to find the limit of the function as x goes to $0$ then the function is not defined there so I used a=0 and got $|x| = 0 $ since it can't be lower than 0 by definition of absoulute value and we know the normal defintion works for values greater than 0 so I checked what happens when $|x-a| = 0 $. now I got to $|x| = 0$ and we know that x can't be 0 since it is not defined, so is this enough for the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the function is not defined at the point then the second definition indeed makes no sense. You can also show that even if the function is defined at the point the definitions are still different. Let's look at the function $f(x)=0$ for all $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=1$. By the standard definition we obviously have $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0$. However, if we can take the point $x=0$ itself then at this point we will get $|f(x)-0|=1$. Hence if we take $\epsilon=1$ then at $x=0$ we will have $|f(x)-0|\geq\epsilon$.

These are the two reasons why we only ask $0<|x-a|<\delta$. The function might not be defined at $a$, or it might be defined but the value is not equal to the limit. In limits we are interested in what happens when we get closer to the point, not what is the value in the point itself.

Comment: why will we always get $|f(x) -0| ≥ \epsilon $ ?

Comment: We defined $f(0)=1$. So if $x=0, \epsilon=1$ then $|f(x)-0|=1\geq\epsilon$. Maybe the word "always" was not needed here, I removed it from the answer.

Comment: why is this incorrect? I just proved the same definition but with $\epsilon≥|f(x)-L|$ so could'nt I say the same?

Comment: The standard definition says that for a given $\epsilon>0$ there must be some $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. It's just that at the specific point $x=a$ we might still have $|f(x)-L|\geq\epsilon$.

Comment: my point is that if epsilon might equall to the absolute value then sure it still works but how could the absolute value be bigger?

Comment: Well, if we take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ then in my example we will have $|f(x)-0|>\epsilon$ when $x=0$. So now the absolute value is really bigger, not even equal.